# new Android Layout Editor missing everywhere

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have read all the tips about "Open With.." to get the new Layout editor in eclipse. Unfortunately I do not see the Layout editor anymore on any list, even on the preferences.
There is a Legacy one, but I suppose it's not the right one.

I used to see the new layout editor once, but then I wanted to check the xml code. After that, no more layout editor.

Comment: Don't know why they downvoted you, I lost that "graphical layout" tab too, looked for it for an hour before finding the answer here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Right click` on an xml layout file and choose `Open With | Android Common XML Editor` then choose `Graphical Layout` tab.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it's correct, but I can't reproduce my initial problem. I solved by creating a new project and somehow the Android Layout Editor appeared again.

Comment: current as of Jan 2013, hard to find coming from XCode iOS background, thanks!